# websocket relay with Autobahn python

Tags: python, json, audio, websocket, autobahn

I am trying to build a websocket server using Autobahn python which acts as a man-in-the-middle or relay for IBM Watson's text-to-speech service. I have already managed to receive and forward the streaming audio from the client to Watson by use of a queue, and I am receiving back transcription hypotheses as JSON data from Watson to my server, but I am not sure how to then forward that JSON data on to the client. It seems that the Watson transcription-side callback and the Autobahn client-side callback exist independently and I can't call a routine from one callback within the other or access data from one callback within the other.

Do I need to set up some kind of shared text message queue? I am sure it should be something simple but I think the problem may be my lack of understanding of the "self" keyword which seems to be isolating the two routines. Would also appreciate any resources on understanding "self".

```py
# For Watson
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
from threading import Thread
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
# For Autobahn
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
    WebSocketServerFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor

try:
    from Queue import Queue, Full
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue, Full

###############################################
#### Initalize queue to store the recordings ##
###############################################
CHUNK = 1024
BUF_MAX_SIZE = CHUNK * 10
# Buffer to store audio
q = Queue(maxsize=int(round(BUF_MAX_SIZE / CHUNK)))
# Create an instance of AudioSource
audio_source = AudioSource(q, True, True)

###############################################
#### Prepare Speech to Text Service ########
###############################################

# initialize speech to text service
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('secretapikeycanttellyou')
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)

# define callback for the speech to text service
class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_transcription(self, transcript):
        print(transcript)

    def on_connected(self):
        print('Connection was successful')

    def on_error(self, error):
        print('Error received: {}'.format(error))

    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        print('Inactivity timeout: {}'.format(error))

    def on_listening(self):
        print('Service is listening')

    def on_hypothesis(self, hypothesis):
        print(hypothesis)
        #self.sendMessage(hypothesis, isBinary = false)
        # HOW TO FORWARD THIS TO CLIENT?

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        #self.sendMessage(data, isBinary = false)
        # HOW TO FORWARD THIS TO CLIENT?

    def on_close(self):
        print("Connection closed")

# define callback for client-side websocket in Autobahn
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")
        recognize_thread = Thread(target=recognize_using_weboscket, args=())
        recognize_thread.daemon = True
        recognize_thread.start()

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            # put audio in queue
            q.put(payload)
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

        # echo back message verbatim
        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)
    
    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))
        
## this function will initiate the recognize service and pass in the AudioSource
def recognize_using_weboscket(*args):
    mycallback = MyRecognizeCallback()
    speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(audio=audio_source,
                                             content_type='audio/l16; rate=16000',
                                             recognize_callback=mycallback,
                                             interim_results=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://127.0.0.1:9001")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

    reactor.listenTCP(9001, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

It seems I need to bridge the gap between `MyRecognizeCallback()` and `MyServerProtocol()`. Please also let me know if this is a terrible implementation of what I am trying to accomplish. I know there are easier ways to relay websocket data but I wanted to familiarize myself with the websocket API/ audio streaming and text messages since eventually I want to cut Watson from the equation and use my own transcription algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074669/how-do-i-send-input-from-python-cmd-to-autobahn-websocket-client-running-in-the), it seems that my efforts to call `MyServerProtocol().sendMessage(u"this is a message2".encode('utf8'))` from `main` were in fact creating a new and unrelated instance of MyServerProtocol rather than piping messages into the existing connection. I was able to send new messages into the open websocket connection using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799754/sendmessage-from-outside-in-autobahn-running-in-separate-thread).

Here is my final code, which still needs some work, but the relevant definition is `broadcast_message`. It was also necessary to 'subscribe' myself to the websocket `onConnect` and 'unsubscribe' `onClose` for this method to work:

```py
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
from threading import Thread
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
# For autobahn
import json
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
    WebSocketServerFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor

try:
    from Queue import Queue, Full
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue, Full

###############################################
#### Initalize queue to store the recordings ##
###############################################
CHUNK = 1024
# Note: It will discard if the websocket client can't consumme fast enough
# So, increase the max size as per your choice
BUF_MAX_SIZE = CHUNK * 10
# Buffer to store audio
q = Queue(maxsize=int(round(BUF_MAX_SIZE / CHUNK)))
# Create an instance of AudioSource
audio_source = AudioSource(q, True, True)

###############################################
#### Prepare Speech to Text Service ########
###############################################

# initialize speech to text service
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('secretapikey')
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)

# define callback for the speech to text service
class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_transcription(self, transcript):
        # Forward to client
        MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message(transcript)

    def on_connected(self):
        print('Connection was successful')

    def on_error(self, error):
        # Forward to client
        MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message('Error received: {}'.format(error))

    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        # Forward to client
        MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message('Inactivity timeout: {}'.format(error))

    def on_listening(self):
        print('Service is listening')

    def on_hypothesis(self, hypothesis):
        # Forward to client
        MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message(hypothesis)

    def on_data(self, data):
        # Forward to client
        MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message(data)

    def on_close(self):
        print("Connection closed")
        MyServerProtocol.broadcast_message("Connection closed")

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    connections = list()

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))
        self.connections.append(self)
        # Start recognizer on connection
        recognize_thread = Thread(target=recognize_using_weboscket, args=())
        recognize_thread.daemon = True
        recognize_thread.start()

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            # Put incoming audio into the queue
            try:
                q.put(payload)
            except Full:
                pass # discard
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

    @classmethod
    def broadcast_message(cls, data):
        payload = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False).encode('utf8')
        for c in set(cls.connections):
            reactor.callFromThread(cls.sendMessage, c, payload)
      

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))
        self.connections.remove(self)
  
## this function will initiate the recognize service and pass in the AudioSource
def recognize_using_weboscket(*args):
    mycallback = MyRecognizeCallback()
    speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(audio=audio_source,
                                            content_type='audio/l16; rate=16000',
                                            recognize_callback=mycallback,
                                            interim_results=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://127.0.0.1:9001")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

    reactor.listenTCP(9001, factory)
    reactor.run()
```